# How can i apply two different curve guides to two different emitters?

Tags: particles, path

First of all, I'm an absolute rookie as it comes to Blender but I'm trying to make a simple project for my dad's company. It's didn't seem hard at first but I've been stuck for ages now so here I am.

I want to have a stream of blue and red balls which eventually seperate in a specific area (blue goes right, red goes left). I think i need to use two emitters as the particles need to split up halfway. But when i apply two curve guides nothing seems to happen (maybe they cancel eachother out) or just some glitch effect eventually appears on my screen. I've tried parenting the curved guides to their specific emitter but this doesn't seem to work as well.

Anyone knows how to solve this? Thanks in advance!